# How to calculate confidence score from CvSVM

Tags: opencv, svm, libsvm

I've trained a two-class SVM, one for Accept and one for Reject. In my application, I'd rather have false acceptance then a false rejection. So I think I'd like to calculate a confidence score and empirically choose a threshold which is biased toward acceptance. The following thread discussed using SVM.decision_func directly with the support vector:
[Obtaining weights in CvSVM, the SVM implementation of OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033363/obtaining-weights-in-cvsvm-the-svm-implementation-of-opencv)

But I'm not sure how to put it all together, particularly using the support vector with the actual test feature matrix to calculate a final scalar confidence score. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just call [CvSVM::predict](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-predict) with the returnDFVal param set to true, and it will return distances instead of class-labels

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it was so obvious! ... It does seem that the decision value is opposite of the class label value. That is, if Accept=1 and Reject=-1, I'm seeing that the decision value of Accept is less than 0, and the decision value of Reject is greater than 0. Does that make sense?